# Can i redirect items that are being deleted

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a client with over 30 sharepoint sites. He wants all deleted items to be kept forever and stored in 1 folder for all of his sites.

Is this even possible and if so can someone explain what to do?

Comment: Looks like a "Custom" Recycle bin at the site collection level that never to be emptied!

Answer (score 0):

For the default recycle bin, that is not possible. It will finally get deleted permanently after a certain period of time. Have a check on this [official doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restore-deleted-items-from-the-site-collection-recycle-bin-5fa924ee-16d7-487b-9a0a-021b9062d14b#:%7E:text=In%20SharePoint%2C%20items%20are%20retained,or%20empties%20that%20Recycle%20Bin.) you can get more information.

For your client, what is his intention of **deleting**? If he simple does not want to keep that file in certain location, and then archive that file, there are better approaches.

Say you client could create a separate site (call it File Center) holding all the files. Then when he wants to "delete" that file, simply use the [move to](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/move-or-copy-files-in-sharepoint-00e2f483-4df3-46be-a861-1f5f0c1a87bc) feature to move the file to that file center. Besides, for automation, you can create flows which triggered on certain days after the last modification/creation, move the file to the file File center site.